# Getting Error when trying to CREATE a converted Data frame to a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to create a CSV file from a database. All the files are in the same directory. I have this code:

```
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv("2018_Central_Park_Squirrel_Census_-_Squirrel_Data.csv")
grey_squirrels_count = len(data[data["Primary Fur Color"] == "Gray"])
red_squirrels_count = len(data[data["Primary Fur Color"] == "Cinnamon"])
black_squirrels_count = len(data[data["Primary Fur Color"] == "Black"])
print(grey_squirrels_count)
print(red_squirrels_count)
print(black_squirrels_count)

data_dict = {
    "Fur Color": ["Gray", "Cinnamon", "Black"],
    "Count": [grey_squirrels_count, red_squirrels_count, black_squirrels_count]
}

print(data_dict)

df = pandas.DataFrame(data_dict)
print(df)

df.to_csv("squirrel_count.csv")
```

But I get this error:

[image: error message]

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Are you sure the dupe answer is appropriate?  This code is trying to open the file for **write**, not **read**.

Comment: I see that the error message refers to line 80 of your code.  The code posted here does not have 80 lines, so clearly this is not your real code.  Your real code must be doing something else that is causing the error.  Can you post your real full code?

Comment: @JohnGordon Hmm, puzzling. It can't be the *other* common duplicate, either, because if the `read_csv` call succeeded (in order to get this far) and the relative path for `to_csv` is just the file name, then there should be no question that the intended containing directory already exists. However, it will definitely still take a proper [mre] to showcase a distinct problem here.

Comment: Off the top of my head, the only reason I can think of for this error is that they have somehow removed the current directory...

Comment: Show error messages and other textual information as properly formatted text in the question, not as comment, image or external link.

Comment: @JohnGordon is right. Try to `import os` module and run `print(os.getcwd())` just before `df.to_csv('...')`. The same exception should be raised.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works as per the below screenshot.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IARcP.png)

So, your error seems like a location/permission issue. Try placing the python script and the input csv file both in the same folder somewhere you have full permissions like your Desktop. Don't use a network drive or system folders.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).